# Low Voltage between Neutral and Ground wires in Dishwasher Junction Box

Tags: dishwasher, junction-box

[image: Bosch Junction Box]My Bosch 800 series Dishwasher will not function. I plan on swapping the control module. In the junction box, at the terminals, I'm reading 120V between Hot and Ground, and between Hot and Neutral. Between Neutral and Ground, I am reading almost zero to 1V. Is this a normal reading between these two terminals, or should I consider swapping the junction box, as well?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. One of our pros will answer more authoritatively, but I'm pretty sure that's what you should expect. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: Have you checked the door switches? There is also going to be a thermal fuse that may be bad. What has you contemplating it is a control unit? (it certainly can be). The voltage you are measuring sounds good. You shouldn't see voltage between GND and NEUTRAL, but its LESS than a volt its most likely noise. Is there anything else connected to this same circuit?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. When I open the door and press ON, there is a very faint beep. That’s why I thought the operating module/controller would be the most likely fix. The garbage disposal is also on the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, because of voltage drop

If you've ever done a voltage drop calculation, let's say you want to run a 12A well pump load.  You do the calculations and it says you'll have 6 volts of voltage drop, so 114V.  OK.

Well, how does that happen?  There are TWO wires - hot and neutral.  Is the voltage drop shared across both?  Yes.  Each one drops 3 volts.

Well, how does "dropping" voltage on a neutral work?  Certainly the hot sags to 117V, no question there.  Obviously if the neutral sags to -3 volts, there'd still be 120 across hot and neutral, so that can't be it.   **Actually, the neutral "drops" the other direction - it rises to +3 volts.** So with neutral at 3V, and hot at 117, you have the expected 114V.

Why doesn't ground move also?  Voltage *drop* is proportional to current; that's literally what Ohm's Law is saying. `E=IR`.  Since there is no current on ground, it doesn't drop.

So you measure 3V between neutral and ground in that case.

It's rather like the small rod on a beam-type torque wrench.  Your strength is bending the big rod, but the small rod is unaffected and indicates your torque on the scale.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage measurements are normal any reading from ~112 to 125 vac hot to neutral is normal throughout the US. A small voltage neutral to ground is also very common.  if the voltage gets above 2.5 volts I have seen switching supplies have problems. But your measurements would point to the controller not the junction box. Having a motor load like a garbage disposal on the same circuit as the dishwasher can create failures as the disposal motor creates large voltage spikes starting and stoping. Adding a surge suppressor to your dishwasher may extend the life of the electronics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a small induced voltage difference is often present, particularly with a flat cord where the ground and neutral are different distance from the hot.